# Adding a tab to commons browsing widget with hook_commons_bw_group_widget()

Tags: 7

I am trying to add a tab to the Commons Browsing Widget so I made a custom module and followed this guide https://drupal.org/node/1782922. I used the first PHP code with hook_commons_bw_group_widget() but it doesn't add the new tab to the widget. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you familiar with the hook-system?
Where did you put the code?

Comment: Please don't add solutions to a question. Post them as an answer. If you are reading it and it isn't posted as an answer, see [revision history](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/95525/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is your module, but this one accomplishes just that:
https://drupal.org/project/commons_bw_ui

It was posted just 2 weeks after your post above.